# Custom login page

Tags: iphone, mobile, authentication, customization

Is there any way to customize Facebook login page on mobile devices ?

I am working on the web application which share images from this app on Facebook wall. But I don't want to have in the app those buttons which allowes you to exit the app, or switch to another tab.

I use this meta to disable upper and bottom bars in the Safari

But in the FB Login page is for example button (Get Facebook for iPhone and Browser faster) which switch me to the Appstore.

I am including this image of facebook login page, where you can see that links which I need to get out :(

http://fotonaut.lukaskosik.com/photo.JPG

Answer (score 1):

You can't tweak this page. It's hosted by Facebook and out of your control.